# Sound Stopped working on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, audio

All of a sudden, sound stopped working on Windows 7. The sound mixer shows sound output, but I can't hear anything on my Creative SB Audigy.

I booted into Ubuntu, and sound worked perfectly, so it's a software problem.

Comment: Please [add](http://superuser.com/posts/302101/edit) more details. What is your hardware? Open Device Manager by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Maintenance, and then clicking Device Manager.‌ What does it show you about your sound card?

Comment: Creative SB Audigy. Doesn't say any more. Anyway, it was working fine an hour ago. I tried restarting, it just won't work.

Comment: So you've got the correct speakers/headphones selected under playback devices?  Did you update Windows at all recently?  Are the Audigy drivers up to date?

Comment: I have to agree with @Lil' Smokey, Microsoft pushes out hardware drivers through Windows Update and sometimes these drivers cause more issues than they fix.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the drivers *from the original CD*, and it fixed the problem. I must have updated it using windows update by mistake. When I do that it seems to cause trouble.